# New thumbnail feature - how to use in Java

Tags: google-drive-api

I'd like to leverage the new thumbnail feature of Google Drive using the latest Java SDK.
But all I get is a bad request response.
Can someone post a working example of this feature?
I've been simply setting the mimetype and Base64-encoded image data but this does not work - at least for file.insert and file.patch.

Update:
This is my (simplified) code snippet. It works fine without the new thumbnail stuff - and the encoded image data looks ok as well:

```
...
Drive drive = getDrive(account);
File file = new File();
file.setTitle(name);
...
HTTPResponse response = urlFetch.fetch(new URL(imageUrl));
String encodedImage = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(response.getContent()));
Thumbnail thumbnail = new Thumbnail();
thumbnail.setImage(encodedImage);
thumbnail.setMimeType("image/png");
file.setThumbnail(thumbnail);
file = drive.files().insert(file).execute();
```

This is the response:

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 400 OK
{
  "code" : 400,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Bad Request",
    "reason" : "badRequest"
  } ],
  "message" : "Bad Request"
}
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:143)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.execute(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:187)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.GoogleClient.executeUnparsed(GoogleClient.java:279)
    at com.google.api.client.http.json.JsonHttpRequest.executeUnparsed(JsonHttpRequest.java:207)
```

Comment: The 400 Bad Request response should include a descriptive error message telling why the request is invalid. Can you show your code and the complete response?

Comment: Can you output the Base 64 encoded string so we can try it out please?

Comment: By the way can you use Base64.encodeBase64String() instead of new String(Base64.encodeBase64(...

Comment: Could you just print the string returned by Base64.encodeBase64String()? so we can check it is correct, try it on our side and in case there is a bug send it as an example in our team?

Comment: The bytes need to be URL-safe Base64-encoded so the correct Java method should probably be Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString()

Comment: I'll try tomorrow and will let you know. Thanks for the responses so far!

Answer (score 0):

The thumbnail image needs to be encoded as a Base64 UrlSafe String.
Using

```
String encodedImage = Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString(response.getContent());
```

to encode the image fixed the issue.